# Can connect to VNC only when computer is connected to another vnc server

Tags: router, ip, port, vnc

I am having issues with a VNC. I am currently using Windows XP with UltraVNC. I am unable to connect to a vnc server. The only way for me to connect to the server is if I am connected to another VNC Server using the viewer.

```
Computer A
    |
Computer B

Computer C
```

Basically computer A can only view and can only be viewed if Computer B is connected to it via vnc. Computer C can see B without having any other VNC connections present. It's almost like ports are blocked when I am no longer connecting out. Previously I was able to connect to A, B, and C just fine. I have configured ports 5500 and 5900 in my routers firewall. Is there any reason why this should be happening?

I also used Microsofts tool called port query. I put in my external IP address and queried the port 5900 TCP and it came back with this message:

```
Starting portqry.exe -n 12.34.56.78 -e 5900 -p TCP ...

Querying target system called:

 12.34.56.78

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

IP address resolved to 12.34.56.78.p0.tel.com

querying...

TCP port 5900 (unknown service): FILTERED
portqry.exe -n 12.34.56.78 -e 5900 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000002.
```

Here is what happens when I am not connected to a VNC using my vnc viewer

```
Starting portqry.exe -n 12.34.56.78 -e 5900 -p TCP ...

Querying target system called:

 12.34.56.78 

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...

IP address resolved to 12.34.56.78 .tel.com

querying...

Error opening socket: 10065

No route to host. 
portqry.exe -n 12.34.56.78 -e 5900 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000063.
```

I have obviously changed the Ip address, but is there anyone who knows what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is behind a nat firewall/router, you have to do more than open a port in the firewall. You have to forward the port to the server.

So, if your router's external address is: 12.34.56.78
And your server's internal address is 192.168.1.2

Then you need to forward port 5900 on your router to 192.168.1.2:5900 which is your server.

Your correct in that 12.34.56.78 is not responding to connections. It's filtering all incoming connections.

Comment: Yes, thank you soooo much!! I see that I had the correct IP adderss in the prot forwarding but there was a previous one that was wrong. the Ip Address is  dynamic, so I will change that to static and it should not break inthe future!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like stunnel to set up a simple tunnel over a different port and forward that port on your router. Personally I prefer port 443 which should already be unlocked and (unlike port 80) should not go through a proxy server. Also note that most free VNC application does not offer encryption and stunnel gives you an encrypted tunnel.

You can find configuration files example for stunnel here:
http://faq.gotomyvnc.com/fom-serve/cache/33.html
Just change 7777 to 443 (or whatever port you'd like to go through the net).

Note that you then connect to 127.0.0.1 in VNC and stunnel on a client send you to the IP you set in the stunnel.conf file.

You could also use SSH but I find setting up stunnel much simpler as you don't even need to install it (just run before connecting).